# How to load components conditionally in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is from a new starter of ReactJS. Unavailability of easily graspable resources has prompted me to knock at SO again. The issue is this. I have a React Component namely, `RegisterAccount` which when clicked shoots another component (a pop-up) allowing users to fill in the required details to register an account. Now once an account is successfully registered, I want to add the registered account as another component under `RegisterAccount`. How can I have this communication set up?

```
//In RegisterAccount
<addAccount/> //pop-up
<accountAdded/> //if account added, then show this component
```

Comment: The gist would be the `<div>{isAccountAdded ? <accountAdded /> : <addAccount />}</div>` — this is just JavaScript so you can encode arbitrary logic in you component's render method.

Comment: Hi @andreypopp , thanks but am afraid this is not what i want. Say RegisterAccount has an icon which when clicked has to pop-up the component AddAccount and once an account is registered somehow RegisterAccount has to know that a registration has happened (probably from AddAccount) and then it should have the AccountAdded component in it. And this should repeat everytime the icon on RegisterAccount is clicked.
How do i set up this communication?

Answer (score 31):

I'm new to React. I was also finding how. and I saw this [article](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/690)!
It says like belows

```
render : function()
{
    return (
        <div>
        { true && <AddAccount /> }
        { false && <AccountAdded /> }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Simple yet effective. There is no need to add inlined styles to hide the Component conditionally. Thanks ;)

Comment: This is a nice solution, although not an obvious one

Comment: The `render` function doesn't render variables with `null` so you could write `let yourComponent = null;` and later (in a condition) `yourComponent = <YourComponent />;` then in your `render` just write `{ yourComponent }`.

Answer (score 18):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to update which component to display when the state changes (e.g. the user creates an account), with that state being altered by a child component. Here is a basic example showing child -> parent communication.

In this case, the `RegisterAccount` component is a root component. If it was a child of another component(s) which also needed to know the `hasAccount` state used in this example, then the state would likely be better off stored higher up the chain (and passed down as a prop).

[jsfiddle of this example](http://jsfiddle.net/8Z49K/1/)

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var AddAccount = React.createClass({
  handleRegistration: function() {
    this.props.updateAccount(true);
  },
  render: function() {
    return <a onClick={this.handleRegistration}>Create my account</a>;
  }
});

var AccountAdded = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <span>Account exists now</span>;
  }
});

var RegisterAccount = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      hasAccount: false
    };
  },
  updateAccountStatus: function(status) {
    this.setState({
      hasAccount: status
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.hasAccount ? <AccountAdded /> : <AddAccount updateAccount={this.updateAccountStatus} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.renderComponent(<RegisterAccount />, document.body);
```

Comment: It seems like React.renderComponent( is outdated.
Works for me using: ReactDOM.render( instead

Comment: @mpaepper Yes. `React.renderComponent` is deprecated. You should `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';` and use `ReactDOM.render(<RegisterAccount />, document.body);` instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do the following and depending on the property **condition** returning true or false you can render  or not. This is just an example, the condition might as well come from a method etc etc..:

```
export class MyClass extends React.Component{
    ...
    render(){
            <div>
                <img src='someSource' />
                {this.state.condition ? <MyElement /> : null}
            </div>
    }
}
```

you can also find more detailed information [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html).

Answer (score 2):

In your render function you can have a variable with your tag that is conditionally displayed...sort of like this:

```
render: function(){
   var conditionalTag;
   if(conditionalTag)   <AccountAdded/>

   return (
      <AddAccount/>
      { conditionalTag } 
   )

}
```

conditionalTag will only be rendered if the variable has jsx in it