# How to un-render component when user come from mobile device?

Tags: reactjs

I need to un-render some react component for mobile user

How to un-render component when user come from mobile device?

Thanks

Comment: You can simply use mobile detect https://github.com/hgoebl/mobile-detect.js

Answer (score 5):

I think this would be a simple solution:

Outside component:

```
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};
```

Inside component:

```
React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      isMobile: isMobile.any(),
      ...
    }
  },
  ...
  render: function() {
    { // base the display of the component on the boolean this.state.isMobile
```

If the if/else becomes more complex than a simple ternary, be sure to move it out of render() to a helper.

Hope this helps!

Edit: This could help with your conditional rendering if that isn't something you've done a ton of. [How to load components conditionally in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21278299/how-to-load-components-conditionally-in-reactjs?rq=1)

Mobile testing code source: http://www.abeautifulsite.net/detecting-mobile-devices-with-javascript/

Comment: That doesn't unmount the component, like OP wanted.

Comment: True -- if 'not rendering' isn't what you're looking for, you can use the same logic outside the component, but use this:  

React.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('mobile-container'));

Comment: @Andrelton You might want to give [proper attribution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13819253/2054072) about a huge part of your answer...